# Is there a way to change the service account from "This account" to "Log in as" using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

New to powershell but bear with me. I am trying to automate an install of Prosystem Fx Engagement, but need to install a SQL instance. I have already done this part, but I will also need to automate the changing of a services account within services.msc. It will need to be changed from "This account" to "Log in as Local System Account"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDrHb.jpg

The name of the service is MSSQL$PROFXENGAGEMENT, and the display name of the service is SQL Server (PROFXENGAGEMENT).

I don't really want to use the method below because the password is visible on the .ps file. I tried looking around but was not able to find anything. Is this even possible?

```
$LocalSrv = Get-WmiObject Win32_service -filter "name='MSSQL$PROFXENGAGEMENT'"
$LocalSrv.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$false,"DOMAIN\administrator","PASSWORD")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the method you are saying you don't want to use for the account change activity. You don't have to and should not put plain text password in scripts.

You can prompt for the password, store that in a variable and use it. Yet, that means a human has to be there to address that, so, not very automated.

So, this means you need to set the credentials in a file or other store and call that from your script.

Meaning like what is described below. This of course has to be done in advance of any other use case that will need it.

[using secure password with multiple users without prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265062/using-secure-password-with-multiple-users-without-prompt)

```
#saving credentials
Get-Credential | Export-CliXml -Path c:\credential.xml

#importing credentials to a variable
$Credential = Import-CliXml -Path c:\credential.xml
```

A YouTube Video on the topic:
[Learn to securely use Passwords with PowerShell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVZAbQEkegU)

You could also use the Windows Credential Store, and call it from there. Also shown in the above video.

[Using Windows Credential Manager](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-PowerShell/Store-password-in-Windows-credential-manager-and-use-it-in/td-p/36192)

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/1.0

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29061982/Powershell-Using-credentials-stored-in-Credential-Manager.html

Comment: Thank you! I have stored my password into Credential Manager and it is passing through successfully! using ```$managedCred.username,$managedCred.GetNetworkCredential().Password ``` instead of strings

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. Be sure to mark as your accepted answer for the benefit of others that may be looking for similar needs.